# Aptana PHP Autocomplete Bug

Tags: php, aptana3

I have a really cracy problem/error in Aptana 3.1.1.

If I type `__` I get autocomplete suggestions. If I type `function __` I don't get anything. Please see attached screenshot.

[image: Aptana 3 Autocomplete Bug]
Any ideas?

Comment: How could an IDE possibly predict what you might want to call a function you are about to write?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Aptana 3 has an build in PHP Editor and as you can see on the icon near the file name - this php editor is used. And the funny thing is, that if i type "__" in a blank new line or after "xyz __", I get the suggestions shown above. Only if I type "public function __" or "function __", I don't get any suggestions.

Comment: yeah happens to me too. this could possibly be a minor bug. Try reporting it. Aptana lately has been coming out with lots of updates. If its minor, theyll fix it.

Comment: What do you actually expect to happen? All those magic functions are meant to be implemented inside a class, if at all. Since you're not inside a class, none of them will do anything magical, so there's no point in suggesting those names. If anything, I would say screenshot #2 is more problematic, because you're not inside a class and you shouldn't call those methods directly anyway.

Comment: @redskins80: Thanks! I have already reported this issue.

Comment: @DCoder: I know, that the magic functions should apear inside a class. But I wanted to show a simple one line example. Even if I reproduce this inside a class, I don't get an suggestion. What I expect is, that if I type "public function __" (inside a class), that I see suggestions for magic functions.

Comment: @leftjustified: An example should highlight your problem, not obscure it. Now that you clarified your issue, I agree with redskins - visit the Aptana bug tracker, see if this is a known issue, report it if it's not. Not much chance that someone on SO would be able to help.